# Printing an intermediate output produced by a customized function in dplyr R

Tags: r, for-loop, dplyr

## Purpose

I have a customized function that takes a list of variables, and for each variable it chooses another variable within the dataframe to create a fitted value between two variables. I would like to print the summary of regression output when I run this in `dplyr`. It would be easier to see the function below to understand what I try to achieve.

## The Customized Function

```
  prisma_fn_add_fitted_fam <- function(d, vars){
    for(i in 1:length(vars)){
      varname <- gsub(paste0(str_extract(vars[i], "[0-9]+")[[1]], '.', sep = ''),"7.",vars[i])
      lag <- gsub(paste0(str_extract(vars[i], "[0-9]+")[[1]], '.', sep = ''),"6.",vars[i])
      
      d <- 
        d %>%
        set.name(vars[i], 'xyz') %>% 
        set.name(lag, 'wxy')
      
      s <-
        lm(xyz ~ wxy, d) 
      
      d <- 
        d %>% 
        modelr::add_predictions(s) %>% 
        rename(!!varname := pred) %>% 
        set.name('xyz', vars[i]) %>% 
        set.name('wxy', lag)
    }
    print(summary(s)) # It does not print. 
    d
  }
```

Comment: The print command is outside the loop so you'll only ever see the result of the last iteration.  If you want to see every iteration move it inside the loop.

Comment: @27ϕ9 in that case, the `s` will be the last iteration in the for-loop. Is it correct? I would like to print all `s` in the loop.

Comment: Why not put `print(summary(s))` just after `s <- lm(xyz ~ wxy, d)` ? It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).